# WooCommerce Paypal

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, currency

I need some help in completing this, my woocommerce is in AED, and I want to use Paypal.

I have succeeded in adding the following codes, however when I test to purchase I get "INTERNAL ERROR" this is code which I have used, on the checkout page, I get internal server error.

I have added step 1 and step 2 codes

```php
    *Step 1 Code to add AED currency symbol in WooCommerce:*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_supported_currencies', 'add_aed_paypal_valid_currency' );       
   function add_aed_paypal_valid_currency( $currencies ) {    
   array_push ( $currencies , 'AED' );  
   return $currencies;    
}

    /*Step 2 – Code to change 'AED' currency to ‘USD’ before checking out with Paypal through WooCommerce:*/

add_filter('woocommerce_paypal_args', 'convert_aed_to_usd', 11 );  
function get_currency($from, $to){
  $from = "USD";
  $to = "AED"; 

  // create curl resource 
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  // set url 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v5/convert?q={$from}_{$to}&compact=ultra"); 

  //return the transfer as a string 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

  // $output contains the output string 
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  // close curl resource to free up system resources 
  curl_close($ch); 
  $data = explode(':', $output);
  $data = explode(" ", $data[1]);
  $amnt = round($data[0], 2);
  return $amnt;
}
function convert_aed_to_usd($paypal_args){
    if ( $paypal_args['currency_code'] == 'AED'){  
    $convert_rate = get_currency(); //Set converting rate
    $paypal_args['currency_code'] = 'USD'; //change AED to USD  
    $i = 1;  
        while (isset($paypal_args['amount_' . $i])) {  
            $paypal_args['amount_' . $i] = round( $paypal_args['amount_' . $i] / $convert_rate, 2);
            ++$i;  
        }  
        if ( $paypal_args['shipping_1'] > 0 ) {
            $paypal_args['shipping_1'] = round( $paypal_args['shipping_1'] / $convert_rate, 2);
        }
        if ( $paypal_args['discount_amount_cart'] > 0 ) {
            $paypal_args['discount_amount_cart'] = round( $paypal_args['discount_amount_cart'] / $convert_rate, 2);
        }
        if ( $paypal_args['tax_cart'] > 0 ) {
            $paypal_args['tax_cart'] = round( $paypal_args['tax_cart'] / $convert_rate, 2);
        }

    }
    return $paypal_args;  
}
```

---

The error I get when i click on check out to complete payment is "INTERNAL ERROR" can anyone help in successfully completing this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxGMB.jpg

Comment: Try after replacing "*Step 1 Code to add AED currency symbol in WooCommerce:*/" to "/*Step 1 Code to add AED currency symbol in WooCommerce:*/"

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you show me exactly how you mean? I don't seem to understand, can you show, please?

Comment: You can check exact error in your console. 
First you need to enable error reporting in wp-config.php
Got to check out page and open console using "F12" key. Navigate to Networks tab. Click on button and you will find ajax call response in console and tell me what exact error shown in it.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik, the payment gateway I am using will fix it. but would be nice to know the full solution.

Comment: Sure. If you would like we can get connected through which I can demonstrate you.